# Is store.unloadAll on ember data 2.18.x suppose to make an ajax call?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**The Context:**

I just updated an Ember App from 2.16 to 2.18.

**The Situation**

In our code, we are manually cleaning up one of our models data by doing:
`store.unloadAll('myModel');` inside an ember.run, the code looks like this:

```
Ember.run(function() {
    store.unloadAll('myModel');
});
```

and I am seeing some ajaxs calls being made to the `.../myModel` endpoints.

**The problem**

I cannot explain why those ajax calls are being done.

**What I have tried**

I am running the  `store.unloadAll('myModel');` outside of the `Ember.run` block, and not seeing the issue any longer, however, I really would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: I recall that there was a bug affecting `store.unloadAll()` some time ago. As you are on a very old version you may be hit by that bug.

Comment: That is the only explanation I got so far too.
Thanks @jelhan